# Assembly GAS Converter hex for binary

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, converters, gnu-assembler

Hi I need to develop converter of hex number to binary number in Assembly GAS. Now I have this:

```
.align 32

SYSEXIT = 1 
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
STDOUT = 1
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0
Input_SIZE = 10

.bss
.lcomm Input, Input_SIZE

.data

msg: .ascii "Give hex number:\n"
msg_len = . - msg

newline: .ascii "\n"
    newline_len = . - newline

.text
.global _start

_start:

mov $SYSWRITE, %eax 
mov $STDOUT, %ebx 
mov $msg, %ecx 
mov $msg_len, %edx 
int $0x80

mov $SYSREAD, %eax 
mov $STDOUT, %ebx
mov $Input, %ecx
mov $Input_SIZE, %edx
int $0x80

    movl %eax, %edi
    movl %eax, %edx     
    dec %edx


loop1:
cmpl $1, %edx
je loop1_exit
movb Input(,%edx,1), %al


            cmpb 0x00, %al
            jl number
            cmpb 0x41, %al
            jg big_char 
            cmpb 0x46, %al
            jl big_char 
            cmpb 0x61, %al
            jg low_char 
            cmpb 0x66, %al
            jl low_char

jmp loop1

number:
    sub $'0', %al   
big_char:
    cmpb $'a', %al
    jae low_char
    sub $'A', %al
    add $10, %al

low_char:
    sub $'a', %al
    add $10, %al

loop1_exit:
movl $SYSWRITE, %eax
    movl $STDOUT, %ebx
    movl $newline, %ecx
    movl $newline_len, %edx
    int $0x80


    movl $SYSEXIT, %eax
    movl $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

and I don't have rally idea what to do next. How to print my binary number in program. I think I need some second loop for print every binary four. This what I have now is ok ?

Answer (score 0):

> This what I have now is ok ?

Run it in debugger and try different inputs, see if the resulting state of CPU is as you expected it (I have some sort of suspicion it will be not exactly what you expect and some changes to code will follow).

> How to print my binary number in program.

For number `12345` (`0x3039`) the binary output is `11000000111001`. So how?

(init part) Let's say you have value in some register r1. Set some other register r2 to zero, except highest bit, for 32b numbers r2 = 0x80000000.

```
to_binary_loop:
    test r1,r2   ; does bitwise AND, discards result, sets up flags
    output( zero_flag ? '0' : '1')
    shr  r2,1    ; moves the bit to right by 1 position
    jnz  to_binary_loop  ; loop till all bits were processed
```

This will display also initial zeroes for full 32b binary output, like `00000000000000000011000000111001`. To avoid that, you may want to put another loop ahead of the first one:

```
to_binary_skip_leading_zeroes:
    test  r1,r2
    jnz   to_binary_found_leading_one
    shr   r2,1    ; next bit
    jnz   to_binary_skip_leading_zeroes
    ; no "1" bit found in r1, enforce at least single 0 to display
    mov   r2,1
to_binary_found_leading_one:
```

---

That `output( zero_flag ? '0' : '1')` .. I would personally write as:

```
    ; somewhere defined (can be even in .text near the loop, read-only usage)
bin_digit: .ascii "01"

    ; in init of loop
    xor   r3,r3   ; pick one of eax,ebx,ecx,edx (spare one), set to zero

    ; during loop after "test r1,r2"
    setnz r3_byte_part
    mov   bin_digit(r3),al  ; al = '0' (ZF=1) or '1' (ZF=0)
    ; output char in "al"
```

---

To any instruction add size suffixes as needed, I'm not going to torture myself with AT&T syntax.